# How does a icmp packet (ping command) work in wireless network?

Tags: android, wifi, icmp

i'm trying to write an app to discover hosts in the network ( like Network Discovery by Aubort), I have a question:
When the android phone send broadcast ping:
-Do the broadcast pings come to wireless router ( or Access point!) and it broadcast them for the phone? And then the wireless router receive and response the ping-echo-reply to the phone? 
-If not the phone have to broadcast pings itself and I think not sure that it's signal quality is as good as wireless router's. So how to make sure that the phone have a complete scan in the network?!
(sorry for my poor English >.<)

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast packets are retransmitted by the access point to other wireless clients (as well as to the wired network).